# Why am I getting this file I/O exception?

Tags: c#, vb.net, file-io

I'm working in code that was machine-translated from Visual Basic 6 to C#.    I'm trying to open a file and read its contents.    It's a simple, short 156 byte text file and the path in strPath is correct and the file can easily be opened in Text Editor

```
ffNum = VBNET.FileSystem.FreeFile();
VBNET.FileSystem.FileOpen(ffNum, strPath, VBNET.OpenMode.Input,
                          VBNET.OpenAccess.Default, VBNET.OpenShare.Default, -1);
int nSize = (int)VBNET.FileSystem.LOF(ffNum);
String thedata = VBNET.FileSystem.InputString(nSize, ffNum);
VBNET.FileSystem.FileClose(new int[] { ffNum });
```

The *InputString* (next to last) line is throwing the IOException "**Bad file name or number**"

How can that be?  The *FileOpen* call didn't throw an exception and the *LOF* didn't either, plus it returned the correct size.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the arguments are the wrong way round. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.inputstring.aspx):

```
Public Shared Function InputString ( _
    FileNumber As Integer, _
    CharCount As Integer _
) As String
```

Note how `FileNumber` is the first parameter, and `CharCount` is the second.

So it looks like the call should be:

```
String thedata = VBNET.FileSystem.InputString(ffNum, nSize);
```

That said, I'd try to avoid this sort of code entirely, and use something like [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) :)

Comment: Bingo.  That order was generated by the automatic translation code so I neglected to check it.  My bad.  Your (you're) good.    I'd love to use a different library but there's 20,000 lines of code and they want it yesterday...